# error in insert command while inserting data into access database

Tags: vb.net

is this command correct for inserting a single value,

```
 "INSERT INTO test (testname) values ('" & txtSelect.Text & "')"
```

actually i'm trying to insert via this command, but its not working..

```
 "INSERT INTO AdmitPt(Bedcategory, BedNo, BedCharges, PtName, PtAge, Address, PhoneNo, 
 Date, BloodGroup, Doctor, Remarks) VALUES('" & CmbBedType.SelectedItem & "', '" & 
 CmbBedNo.SelectedItem & "', " & txtCharges.Text & "', '" & txtPatName.Text & "', '" & 
 txtPatAge.Text & "', '" & txtPatAdd.Text & "', '" & txtPhone.Text & "', '" & 
 dtpDate.Value.ToShortDateString & "', '" & cmbBloodGrp.SelectedItem & "', '" & 
 cmbDoctor.SelectedItem & "',  " & txtRemarks.Text & ")"
```

kindly correct me i'm doing some mistake.

Comment: What type of exception it is generating?

Comment: You dont need the " surrounding the insertstament. But what is the actual error that you get?

Comment: Please can you post the full vb.net code you are using, and not just the SQL query string. 
You really would be better off using addwithvalue parameters instead of concatenating your values into the string.  In fact, really you would be well advised to use a stored procedure.

Comment: you should consider SQL Injection and better use parameterized query to avoid it. also @JonathonCowley has good suggestions for u.

Comment: You need to double up any single quotes that may appear in the source control. I see you last field is not single quoted. Nor is txtCharges. Build the SQL then use the Text Inspector to look at your results in debug.

Comment: If you want to make your life easier create a new item in VS and name it something like insert.sql. Remove all the default code and write your sql into the file using parameters. Add that file as an embeded resource and reference by My.Resource.Insert then use commands add by value. Or if you really want and make your like easier use Simple.Data which you can get through NuGet or GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you posted your entire code - you forgot to actually execute the command. Add

```
comStudent.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

before closing the connection.

Comment: thanks Syed Mohsin & all who helped me to solve the issue. : )

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `Text` property of `SelectedItem`

```
 "INSERT INTO AdmitPt(Bedcategory, BedNo, BedCharges, PtName, PtAge, Address, PhoneNo, 
  Date, BloodGroup, Doctor, Remarks) VALUES('" & CmbBedType.SelectedItem.Text & "', '" & 
 CmbBedNo.SelectedItem.Text & "', " & txtCharges.Text & "', '" & txtPatName.Text & "', '" & 
 txtPatAge.Text & "', '" & txtPatAdd.Text & "', '" & txtPhone.Text & "', '" & 
 dtpDate.Value.ToShortDateString() & "', '" & cmbBloodGrp.SelectedItem.Text & "', '" & 
 cmbDoctor.SelectedItem.Text & "', " & txtRemarks.Text & ")"
```

also `ToShortDateString` is a method and should be writen as `ToShortDateString()`

Comment: Syed Mohsin thanks brother, but the code i've shared for single value is not working also... whta wrong with that?

Comment: no exception is generated, but values are not going to DB.. not stored..

`code`

Answer (score 0):

no exception is generated, but values are not going to DB.. not stored..

`code`

```
   Dim RegNo, BedNo, BedType, Charges, PatName, PatAge, PatAddr, Phone, CheckupDate, BloodGroup, Doctor, Remarks As String


    RegNo = txtRegNo.Text
    BedNo = CmbBedNo.SelectedItem.ToString()
    BedType = CmbBedType.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Charges = txtCharges.Text
    PatName = txtPatName.Text
    PatAge = txtPatAge.Text
    PatAddr = txtPatAdd.Text
    Phone = txtPhone.Text
    CheckupDate = dtpDate.Value.ToShortDateString()
    BloodGroup = cmbBloodGrp.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Doctor = cmbDoctor.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Remarks = txtRemarks.Text

    conStudent.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\DBProject\hspms.mdb"
    conStudent.Open()
    comStudent.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AdmitPt(ID, Bedcategory, BedNo, BedCharges, PtName, PtAge, Address, PhoneNo, Date, BloodGroup, Doctor, Remarks) VALUES('" & RegNo & "', '" & BedType & "', '" & BedNo & "', " & Charges & "', '" & PatName & "', '" & PatAge & "', '" & PatAddr & "', '" & Phone & "', '" & CheckupDate & "', '" & BloodGroup & "', '" & Doctor & "',  " & Remarks & ")"
    comStudent.Connection = conStudent
    comStudent.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    conStudent.Close()
```

`code`

Comment: Please don't post additional info in the answer section. Rather edit your original question.